# To remove the duplicate words from the array and returning the unique to the same array

Tags: java, arrays

I was trying to remove the duplicates from the list of arrays, I was trying to use simple `for` loop instead of `hashset`..

Can anyone suggest how can I improve my program:

```
public class removeduplicates {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] words={"Others","Others","Others","Sentence"};

        String output=words[0];
        int count=0;

        for(int i=0;i<words.length-1;i++) {
            for(int j=i+1;j<words.length;j++) {
                if(words[i].equals(words[j])) {
                    count++;
                }
                else {
                    output=output+words[j];
                }
            }
            i=count;
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

In this program if we give input as Others, Sentence, Others, Sentence then I am not getting the required output: I need just `Others` and `Sentence` as output...

If possible I have a condition that when I am entering words array, I need the output array with only unique values in the same array words.

Comment: Bear in mind that you can't resize an array anyway, so how are you expecting to "remove" elements? I would strongly urge you to use a collection.

Comment: just sort it before you de-duplicate it ,and put the data into the other list, really simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String [] input={"other", "other","sentence","other"};

    String current=input[0];
    boolean found=false;
    for(int i=0; i<input.length; i++){
        if (current == input[i] && !found) {
            found = true;
        } else if (current != input[i]) {
            System.out.print(" " + current);
            current = input[i];
            found = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use collections as you can't resize an array

```
ArrayList<String> noDuplicateList = new ArrayList<>();
String[] words={"Others","Others","Others","Sentence"};
for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++) {
   if(!noDuplicateList.contains(words[i])){
        noDuplicateList.add(words[i]);
    }
}
```

Here's a [link](https://ideone.com/aSim3A)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve the duplication is declared already using `HashSet`, Anyway look at this code using loop:

**Step 1:** replace duplicate value with `null`

```
String[] words={"Others","B","Sentence","A","Others","A","Sentence"};

for(int i=0; i < words.length ;i++) {

    String toBeRemoved = words[i];

    for(int j=i+1 ; j < words.length; j++) {
        if(words[j] != null && words[j].equals(toBeRemoved)) {
            words[i] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you print the `words` values then the output will be:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(words));
```

output: `[null, B, null, null, Others, A, Sentence]`

**Step 2:** Remove the null values (there are many ways to do it) for example:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(words));
list.removeIf(new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(String t) {
        return (t == null || t.length() < 0);
    }
});
words = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Using lambda JDK 8:

```
words = Arrays.stream(words).filter(t -> (t != null && t.length() > 0)).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Now if you print the `words` values then the output will be:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(words));
```

output: `[B, Others, A, Sentence]`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. But in this when I am giving 
String[] words={"Others","Sentence","Others","Sentence"};
its going to an infinite loop it seems.